# How to prevent items from going to another page in Reporting Services 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I currently have the following problem :

i have two matrices in the same report, but the second keep going to a second page. In fact, at anytime, I would like all my documents to fit on one page only. The use of pages in html is just a pain, as it is in excel format, by the way.

My question can thus also be rephrased as this : how to keep all elements of a report on only one page (even if it has to get very long), at least for html and excel output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic206436-150-1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251701.aspx